# Partition SQL WINDOW function on certain criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate a running total of the AddToCart metric that only starts **after** a 'product/search/details' page was seen.

[image]

Here's the link to SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bbf9b/1

In the sqlfiddle link, I've manually created a column to reflect my desiredoutput. The workingoutput column shows where I have gotten to with my code.

```
SUM(AddToCart) OVER (PARTITION BY SessionID ORDER BY HitNumber ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as workingoutput
```

I know the below syntax is all wrong, but this is essentially what I am trying to achieve

```
SUM(AddToCart) OVER (PARTITION BY SessionID ORDER BY HitNumber ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND FIRST_VALUE(ROW LIKE "%/product/search/details%")) as workingoutput
```

Comment: Unfortunately transact-SQL language does not query the content of images. Please provide queries to create the table and insert the sample data. In addition please describe the expected result set according to the sample data and the version of the server which you are using. Thanks

Comment: "I've also tried PARTITION, but **cant seem to get it to work**." Please, do not use generic descriptions because they provide completely no information. Describe the issue you have. With "doesn't work" the only valid answer is "change something in some piece of the code according to the syntax rules"

Comment: `SUM('Add To Cart')`? How do you `SUM` a literal string?

Comment: @astentx - understood

Comment: @RonenAriely - Will try and improve my question. I created sample data rather as I can't provide actual data due to security issues. Will include the actual sample table

Comment: @Larnu - Will adjust my sample data to better convey my question

Comment: Obviously @Chris, we do not ask you to provide the real data but only a sample to reproduce the scenario for the sake of the discussion (which include the need to test). You can use this site in order to publish your demo `http://sqlfiddle.com/` and provide the link to the demo `:-)`

Comment: Do you want the column to be a running sum, or do you want the same value for every row (if so what about the first few rows here, what about rows which are before that event)

Comment: @RonenAriely - thanks for bearing with me (and my first SQL question) Have edited and created the sample data in sqlfiddle as suggested. Please let me know if you have any more feedback :)

Comment: @Charlieface - my desired output is a running sum as better shown in my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest your window functions here

- Start with a running conditional count, checking if we have reached `/product/search/details` yet, and only return `AddToCart` based on that
- Do a running sum over that result

```sql
SELECT
  wd.SessionID,
  wd.HitNumber,
  wd.HitType,
  wd.EventType,
  wd.PageName,
  wd.AddToCart,
  SUM(wd.AddToCartFromSearch) OVER (PARTITION BY wd.SessionID
      ORDER BY HitNumber ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS DesiredOutput
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN wd.PageName = '/product/search/details' THEN 1 END)
                OVER (PARTITION BY wd.SessionID ORDER BY HitNumber ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) > 0
           THEN AddToCart ELSE 0 END AS AddToCartFromSearch
    FROM WebData wd
) wd
ORDER BY HitNumber;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbf9be/4)

Comment: Amazing @Charlieface. Thanks so much!!